# Display XML data from file with unknown extension

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

Is there any way to treat a file with a different extension as an XML file with XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript? - that means being able to display data from file that is basically exactly the same as an XML file, except with a different file extension.

Here is a quick script I grabbed from the W3C demo on: *[How to display XML data in a table](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp)* as an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table><tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This will display the XML data in a table. But if I change the extension of `cd_catalog.xml` to something like `cd_catalog.hsy`, it will not display the file, because it is not an XML file. So how would you override the `.xml` only restriction in JavaScript ?

Comment: What media type is being set by the server on the XHR response?

Comment: @Richard It seems to be text/xml